# How do you apply a glossy node to a specific image texture when using alpha and RGB mix nodes?

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor

I bet it's an easy fix but considering I'm a newbie take it easy will ya, anyway here's my node setup.
[image]

the highlighted nodes contain the transparent image texture I'm attempting to make glossy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're dealing with glossy, you're dealing with shaders, not color anymore, so you'll have to use the "mix shader" node instead of the "color mix" node. It also can be controlled by the alpha output. In my example only the second texture has glossy.

[image]